# Why does my program only print out the last number?

Tags: c

My assignment want me to print out the largest number of 10 numbers.

I think I have nailed the structure right, but my program prints out only the last inserted number :D

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Give 10 numbers > \n");
    int n;
    int largest = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
    if(n > largest){
       largest = n;
    }
    printf("Your largest number is %d", largest);

return 0;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the for loop runs all ten times before the if statement is reached.  The first 9 times through the loop you simply put a value in n and then get a new value for n and overwrite it.  Try moving the if statement inside the for loop so it tests each iteration of n.

Comment: @G.M. Perhaps adding code is better, yet sometimes posting code speaks louder than the explanation and simply serves to feed the give-me-the-code posters.  Without code, OP and others are obliged to follow the answer's good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> Any help?

In addition to [@Delta_G](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77207898/2410359) good answer:

**Wrong max with only negative input**

Once code is fixed by moving the `>` test, if all input values were negative, the max would incorrectly report as 0.  [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207878/why-does-my-program-only-print-out-the-last-number/77208330#comment136111116_77207878)

Various ways to fix.
One is to initialize `max` with the most negative `largest`.

```
// int largest = 0;
int largest = INT_MIN;  // found in <limits.h>
```

**Advanced issues**

What if the entered value is outside the `int` range, non-numeric, incomplete, etc?

Something for another day.